# Where are chrome apps file located on a Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I installed a chrome app on my Pixelbook which has dev mode enabled. I'm trying to find where app is physically installed. Where can I find it?

Tried looking around the web and don't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Check [this help center post (Find & organize apps)](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6206362?hl=en) if this what you think you needing right now.

Comment: nah, I want to know where the actual app source code is located inside a chromebook after I install it.

Answer (score 0):

Am I late to this? Web apps are installed to /home/user//. You can get there by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T to open chrome-untrusted://crosh and typing shell, you might need to enable developer mode.
Android Apps are installed in the Arc VM, Linux Apps are installed in the Termina VM and Steam Apps are installed in the Borealis VM.
I'm not sure where Chrome Apps are installed, but those are being phased out anyway.